# Ubuntu 19.04 display hanging - is it hardware?

Tags: nvidia, suspend, crash, display-manager

I've had a look around but can't find any answers. 
Long time user but still a noob in terms of understanding how it works!

My system keeps locking up a seemingly random amount of time and load after starting. I want to say it only happens after coming back from suspend but it's not true it just hangs quicker after it's been suspended.
Different running apps don't seem to have an effect.

Locking up= whatever is on the screen freezes, mouse pointer often still moving, keyboard num-lock responds once or twice then freezes too.
Have to long press the power button to get it off.

I am assuming its just the display hanging as the minecraft world I share to my kids via LAN keeps working for them..

The few items in the logs marked as 'Important' don't seem to be issues from researching them..

It's a relatively new build so I am keen to ascertain if it is a hardware fault.

Gigabyte B450 I AORUS PRO WIFI
GeForce RTX 2060 - NVidia drivers 430
Ubuntu 19.04 - everything up-to-date

Really grateful for any help; keen to catch anything under warranty if it's broken!!

Comment: Rather than power off, have you tried [magic] sysrq keys to have it shutdown (more messages may appear in journalctl giving you more information). If the sysrq keys don't function, then I'd be more likely to think it's hardware  *I used magic as the wikipedia article refers to them as magic; and that page is as good as any to help yourself remember the keystrokes if you're on a phone as your system is not responding...*

Comment: Thanks for your question: As soon as it hangs I have tried Ctrl+Alt+F1/F2 to try to get into a consol but it doesn't work. Even the three finger salute doesn't work. Are there others I should try to get more info??

Comment: No those are not what I meant; keys caught & operated by the kernel itself; first item on `magic sysrq` search on startpage gives https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key, adding the word `ubuntu` gives https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=617349 and i was thinking of REISUB (Raw [ignore X/gui] tErminate-all kIll Sync (safely close fs) Unmount (protect data) and reBoot) but you can adjust to your needs... (and you'll have to open a link as I'm skipping the ALT+sysrq it starts with; alt remains held down during following commands)

Comment: Awesome stuff; every day is a school day. I'll try RSEIUB when it next freezes and see whats in the logs/post here. Thx!

Comment: So I have a few "NVRM" lines - Xid, attempted to yield - in my syslog that seems to be an issue.

Comment: I have had this problem many times with 16.04. I would just reboot and voilà! It did not happen that often but I never suspend either. I should learn about the sysrq to see if I can find info when it happens again...

Answer (score 1):

SO it seems that the NVIDIA drivers need to be set to 'Prefer Maximum Performance' in the Powermizer settings to avoid this problem. No crashes since setting that.

However it needs to be set every boot which is a pain.

Thanks guiverc for the lesson in Magic keys!